# Suitable way to measure the probability in percentage the similarity between two subject

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithms, conditional-probability, geometric-series

hi I’m looking for the best way to measure the interest of two person through a questionnaire of n questions Off multiple choice questions from Strongly disagree to strongly agree.

Examples:

Question 1: do you like being outdoors?

Person 1 answer: Disagree
Person 2 answer: Strongly agree

Question 2: Do you like doing things for pace?

Person 1 answer: Strongly agree
Person 2 answer: Strongly agree

I’m sorry but I’m new to this forum and thank you in advance

Comment: What specifically are you trying to measure? Are you trying to create some kind of measure for each person, or some kind of measure of similarity between two people?

Comment: @ConMan Yes, the similarity between two people but to be more precise between a person and environment.